# Ошибка при попытке войти в приложение

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, аутентификация, мобильное-приложение

Установил себе приложение `StackExchange` для Андроида, но не могу зайти под аккаунтом в фейсбуке, вот что  пишет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Отправил вопрос ребятам, которые отвечают за приложение, еще в пятницу. Как что–то будет известно, сразу отпишусь!

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky какой статус? :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо за напоминание. Проверил, все работает.